# 'make-series' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'monthlyInterval'

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

New to KQL. I'm trying to create a line chart that counts the page view. The query has a frequency selector (daily, weekly, monthly and yearly). I can't exactly use 30d for one month since not all months have 30 days. This is also true when it comes to the number of days in a year. Trying to come up with a dynamic solution by using case during the 'step' in make-series.

```
let selectedFrequency = "{Frequency}";
pageViews
| where name in ({URL})
| project name, timestamp
| extend monthlyInterval = bin(endofmonth(timestamp)-startofmonth(timestamp), 1d),
    yearlyInterval = bin(endofyear(timestamp)-startofyear(timestamp), 1d)
| make-series CountByPageName=count() default = 0 on timestamp from {TimeRange:start} to {TimeRange:end} step case(
    selectedFrequency == "Monthly", monthlyInterval,
    selectedFrequency == "Yearly", yearlyInterval,
    selectedFrequency == "Weekly", 7d,
    selectedFrequency == "Daily", 1d,
    1d
) by name
| render linechart
```

It's throwing this error:

```
'make-series' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'monthlyInterval'...
```

Tried using `toscalar()` on the monthlyInterval but the same error above shows up, only this time the timestamp is failing to be resolved. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step parameter must be constant and can not changed by every row.
You could calculate the number of the year / month / week or day before using the make-series operator. Example with month:

```
range i from 0 to 365 step 1
| extend timestamp= ago(i*1d)
| extend t = tolong(monthofyear(timestamp))
| make-series CountByPageName=count() default = 0 on t step 1
| render linechart with(xcolumn=t)
```

result:

```
t: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
count: [32,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
```